# Are all parameters to Javascript functions passed only by value?

Tags: javascript

If I have a variable like this:

I created something similar to an ENUM like this:

```
 var ContentStatusId = {
        All: 0,
        Production: 1,
        Review: 2,
        Draft: 3,
        Concept: 4
    }
```

When I call a function like this:

```
doTask(myParam) {
    var a = 
}
```

With doTask(ContentStatusId.All);

Is there any way that I can find out anything about the parameter passed to the function or is it completely passed by value only? Are there any other ways to pass parameters to a function?

Comment: what are you wanting to find out about it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There might be another way to handle it-- like checking for type or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript *all* parameters are passed by value.

In the case of a primitive, the value is the primitive value.

```
function test(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
test(1);
```

`arg` will have the value of 1.

However, if you say

```
test({});
```

then `arg` will contain a value which is a REFERENCE to the object we just created.

**Edit to address comment**

You can do...

```
doTask(myParam) {
  if (myParam === ContentStatusId.Review) {
   // Do stuff
  }
}

doTask(ContentStatusId.Review);
```

or

```
doTask(myParam) {
  switch(myParam) {
     case ContentStatusId.Review:
     // Do stuff
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What I would like to pass is something like "ContentStatusId, Review: 2" so that I can get at the word and the number. Is there a way I could do that by modifying the way I store the variables that I am using like Enums ?

Answer (score 1):

**There is nothing calling pass by reference in javascript.**

Everything gets passed **by value only**.

E.g

If in case of primitive value

e.g

```
var a = 10;

console.log(a); // 10

fun xyz(a); // passing a 

function xyz(a) {
    a += 10;
    console.log(a); // 20
} // function will receive the value. If you modify it, It will still will not be reflected back to what you passed

console.log(a); // 10
```

Other way round,

When you pass object to a function, The references gets copied.

e.g

```
var obj = { 'a': 10 };

console.log(obj.a); // 10

function xyz(obj) {
    obj.a = obj.a + 10;
    console.log(obj.a); // 20
} // here the obj will be copied as reference. So when you modify it, It will get reflected back to original object.

console.log(obj.a); // 20
```